# ninja forms giving restrictions on Datepicker

Tags: javascript, wordpress, datepicker, ninja-forms

I have the ninja forms plugin in my wordpress website for a tailor made tour form. In that form there's a datepicker.

Recently it has started to give me an error when i select the dates. I can only select the dates before current date and two days after current date. When I select a date after the current date (eg: current date- 10/05/2018 | selecting date- 23/05/2018) it gives me the message "Please enter a valid date!" which is considered to be a blocked date.

I googled the heck out of this and still couldn't find a solution. Could someone please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please check this link http://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/datepicker/ may be its helpful for you

Comment: I checked it and I don't have an idea how to implement those codes to my website. Could you please help me on how to add those codes to my website and where to add them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and ended up changing the Format setting of the field from "Default" to "DD/MM/YYYY". Some sort of bug in Ninja Forms I guess. I haven't had time to dig into why yet, so if anyone has a clue, let us know.

Comment: Thank you very much. I contacted ninja forms support and they said it was a bug and they've fixed it with the new update.